# CMFCMaskedEdit GetWindowText not returning current text

Tags: c++, mfc

In my MFC project, a `CMFCMaskedEdit` is used to input Date.

```
m_masked.EnableMask(_T("dddd-dd-dd"), _T("____-__-__"), _T(' '));                        
m_masked.SetValidChars(_T("1234567890")); // Valid string characters

CString sDate = CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%Y-%m-%d"); 

m_masked.SetWindowTextA(sDate);
m_masked.EnableGetMaskedCharsOnly(FALSE);
```

Then I process the `EN_CHANGE` message:

```
ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_MFCMASKEDEDIT1, &CCustListDlg::OnEnChangeMfcmaskededit1)
```

Get current text in the edit:

```
void CCustListDlg::OnEnChangeMfcmaskededit1()
{
    // TODO:  If this is a RICHEDIT control, the control will not
    // send this notification unless you override the CDialog::OnInitDialog()
    // function and call CRichEditCtrl().SetEventMask()
    // with the ENM_CHANGE flag ORed into the mask.

    // TODO:  Add your control notification handler code here
    CString str;
    GetDlgItem(IDC_MFCMASKEDEDIT1)->GetWindowText(str);
}
```

However, the returned string is always the previous text, not the text after editing. How should I get the correct text string ?

Comment: Did you tried to call a UpdateData(TRUE); before retrieve data ?

Comment: [Dialog Data Exchange and Validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange-and-validation).

Comment: @flaviu2 Surely `UpdateData`(..)` is not applicable here? He is mapping to a control and not a variable. Getting the value from the control itself should return the right text. No?

Comment: Yes, I guess you are right.

Comment: Even so, for retrieving data might be necessary to call UpdateData anyway, I am not sure though. I didn't checked this.

Comment: `UpdateData` is required **purely** when opting in to MFC's Dialog Data Exchange model. If you aren't using DDX, you don't need to call `UpdateData` at any time.

Answer (score -1):

My app does something similar, I reformed it to match what you're doing. See if this helps in any way:

```
m_masked.EnableMask(_T("DDDD DD DD"), _T("____-__-__"), _T('0'), _T("1234567890"));
m_masked.EnableGetMaskedCharsOnly(FALSE);
CString sDate = CTime::GetCurrentTime().Format("%Y-%m-%d");
m_masked.SetWindowTextA(sDate);
```

Comment: Isn't he talking about a problem with the result of `GetWindowText` and not how to initialise the control?

Comment: I was looking at how the mask was setup, mine has it initialized within the statement where his requires a call to it....just wondering if there is an issue with the extra statement ...I can't see why, just offering up a possible alternate. Worse case, nothing changes I would expect.